# android.support.v4.app does not exist

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, sdk, cordova-plugins

> ..../cordova/sms_receiver/SmsReceiverPlugin.java:8: error: package
>   android.support.v4.app does not exist
>   import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;

also:

> ..../cordova/sms_receiver/SmsReceiverPlugin.java:121: error: cannot find symbol
>   ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this.cordova.getActivity(), new String[]{type}, requestCode);

and:

> ..../cordova/sms_receiver/SmsReceiver.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Driving me nuts. Trying to build a cordova app for android. I've followed a ton of different google results to try and get rid of this error.

Including adding this to plugin.xml:

```
<framework src="com.android.support:support-v4:+" />
```

also a reference to a build.gradle file with:

```
dependencies: {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:+'
}
```

Also adding numerous paths to $PATH, selecting *everything* in Android SDK manager etc etc, nothing works!

New to this I'll admit, this is on a Mac with Java 1.8 JDK installed. Tried 10.0 also.

I've lost track of all the things I've tried. Please can someone put me out of my misery.

Comment: What cordova plugins do you have installed?

Comment: It's this one https://github.com/rehy/cordova-plugin-sms-receiver

Answer (score 1):

You can probably solve your issue by adding the plugin :

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-android-support-v4

as mentioned here - https://github.com/rehy/cordova-plugin-sms-receiver/issues/7

Comment: I tried this, but think I screwed up as I did an 'npm i --save' being that it was on the npm site. I guess I don't really understand the difference between a node module and a cordova plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Change and import
`androidx.core.content.FileProvider;`

Otherwise

1. `npm install jetifier`
2. `npx jetify`
3. `npx cap sync android`

if your project on native